# why a line containing `\fbox` in my code is not working?

Tags: fbox

I have this line in my code:

```
\fbox{\ker(r \lambda)_* \cong\mathbb{Z}/p^{a+t-\min\{a,b\}}}
```

And this is my document from the beginning

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
% Sprache (neue deutsche Rechtschreibung)
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
% Mathematik
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
 \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
 
\usepackage[margin= 1 in]{geometry}

%\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.875in}
    \addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.575in}
    %\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.75in}

    \addtolength{\topmargin}{-.275in}
    \addtolength{\textheight}{- .1 in}

\title{Master Thesis}
\author{Jacob }
\date{Feb 21}

\begin{document}
```

but the line I mentioned is not compiling, could anyone tell me why my code is not working please?

Comment: The code and sourcecode tags are meant to be used for problems in typesetting source code, not in your document. Moreover, I bet this problem is not restricted to overleaf.

Comment: Did you look at the error message, *viz.*, "Missing $ inserted". This message might have tipped you off that TeX wasn't in math mode when some math-y material was encountered in the argument of `\fbox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents of `\fbox` ("frame box") are processed in text mode by default. Since the argument of your `\fbox` directive is math-y stuff, you need to inform LaTeX to switch to math mode. You can do this by replacing

```
\fbox{\ker(r \lambda)_* \cong\mathbb{Z}/p^{a+t-\min\{a,b\}}}
```

with

```
\fbox{$\ker(r \lambda)_* \cong\mathbb{Z}/p^{a+t-\min\{a,b\}}$}
```

Alternatively, if the passage in question occurs while already in math mode (say, while inside a displayed equation), you might use `\boxed`. E.g.,

```
$ \boxed{\ker(r \lambda)_* \cong\mathbb{Z}/p^{a+t-\min\{a,b\}}} $
```

The macro `\boxed` is provided by the `amsmath` package.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\fbox{$\ker(r \lambda)_* \cong\mathbb{Z}/p^{a+t-\min\{a,b\}}$}

$\boxed{\ker(r \lambda)_* \cong\mathbb{Z}/p^{a+t-\min\{a,b\}}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: To be precise I was writing this line as $$\fbox{\ker(r \lambda)_* \cong\mathbb{Z}/p^{a+t-\min\{a,b\}}}$$ but it did not compile.

Comment: @Happy - For the `\fbox` solution to work with its math-y argument, it doesn't matter that `\fbox{...}` occurred inside a displayed equation. But since you've confirmed that the expression occur within a displayed equation, I would use the `\boxed` approach, not the `\fbox` approach.